# What's the expected behavior for this GET request?

Tags: get, network-programming

For a school assignment I'm creating a basic web server and I'm struggling to understand how I'm supposed to respond to this request in the testing script.

Procedure: Writes "GET /loadavg HTTP/1.0\r\n" to the server, then
                   checks nothing has been returned, and finishes with the
                   extra "\r\n" and checking the data sent back from the
                   server.

---

AssertionError: The http response was returned too early, before the extra
 line.

I'm just trying to understand what the test is actually testing for if this makes sense. Typically, I'd go to a TA but it's Sunday. The /loadavg portion I'm fine with but I'm confused on how the \r\n effects this test or even how to handle it.

Here's the relevant testing code. If anyone is able to shed some light on this and explain what this test is doing, I'd be appreciative.

```
    #Make HTTP connection for the server
    sock = server_check.get_socket_connection(self.hostname, self.port)

    sock.send("GET /loadavg HTTP/1.0\r\n")
    sock.send("Host: " + self.hostname + "\r\n")
    sock.settimeout(1)
    time.sleep(.1)
    try:
        if sock.recv(4096, socket.MSG_PEEK) != '':
            self.fail("The http response was returned too early, before" +\
            " the extra \r\n line.")

    except socket.timeout:
        pass

    sock.send("\r\n")
    #If there is a HTTP response, it should be a valid /loadavg
    #response.
    data = ""

    time.sleep(0.1)
    try:
        while sock.recv(4096, socket.MSG_PEEK) != '':
            msg_buffer = sock.recv(4096)
            data = data + msg_buffer

    #Connections close after responses for HTTP/1.0 , therefore a timeout
    #should not occur.
    except socket.timeout:
        self.fail("The server did not respond and close the connection in sufficient time.")


    data = data.split("\r\n\r\n")
    assert len(data) == 2, \
        "The response could not be parsed, check your use of \\r\\n"

    assert server_check.check_loadavg_response(data[1]), \
        "The /loadavg object was not properly returned."
```

Comment: ah my bad, I'm using C but it's not actually relevant to the question so I'll remove it

Comment: A tool like Wireshark will enabling viewing wire traffic. This test is failing because it expects NO content response before the \r\n "ending" the request header section. Every request header is itself followed by a \r\n so a blank line indicates all the headers are sent.